# Proving $\forall n \in \mathbb Z, n>0, \;\exists x_n\in \mathbb Z$ such that $x_n^2 \equiv 14 \pmod {5^n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Using induction, prove that for every positive integer $n$, there exists an integer $x_n$ such that $$x_n^2 \equiv 14
\mod 5^n$$

My work is shown in the following photos: [First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OEy8.jpg)
[Second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVSZg.jpg)

I really need help with this problem as I'm doing a basic mathematical induction course and the professor did a pretty horrid job at explaining this problem. I also asked four other TA's (teaching assistants) and only one of them was able to explain it but they used the Jacobi symbol, a concept we haven't learned.

PS: if someone can help with the formatting of this question I'd greatly appreciate it as I'm relatively new to this site.

Comment: I presume you mean $x_n^2\equiv14\pmod{5^n}$. Alas I cannot read your work. The buzzword for this is "Hensel lifting". The idea is to set $x_{n+1}=x_n+5^nt$ and prove there is a $t$ that works.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry for the messy work. At this point I'm more focused on trying to solve the problem rather than writing a formal proof...